# Is there an equivalent of LinuxIMQs in BSD?

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, traffic-shaping, pf

Is there an equivalent of LinuxIMQs in BSD ?

From linuximq.net:

The imq device has two common usage cases:

#### Ingress shaping:

With linux only egress shaping is possible (except for the ingress queue which can only do rate limiting). IMQ enables you to use egress qdiscs for real ingress shaping.

#### Shaping over multiple interfaces:

Qdiscs get attached to devices. A consequence of this is that one qdisc can only handle traffic going to the interface it is attached to. Sometimes it is desireable to have global limits on multiple interfaces. With IMQ you can use iptables to specify which packets the qdiscs sees, so global limits can be placed.

Does pf in BSD land (freebsd openbsd ?) have something like this, or that achieves the same thing? I am looking into how to set a maximum thoroughput per each client, while having multiple wan links.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  pf/ALTQ and IPFW/DummyNet can do ingress rate limiting at a logical level. Wire level ingress filtering isn't possible to force on Ethernet. Some protocols can fake being shaped over time, for example limiting ACK rate for TCP.

Comment: PF cannot do incomming traffic shaping, you can only limit outgoing traffic. Although you can prioritize incoming traffic, but not to shape it. http://quigon.bsws.de/papers/2012/bsdcan/ FreeBSD has old version of PF, on FreeBSD it is better to stick with IPFW I think.

Answer (score 0):

If what you like to do is something like that :

```
[ Alice ]    [ Charlie ]
    |             |                              ADSL
 ---+-----+-------+------ dc0 [ OpenBSD ] fxp0 -------- ( Internet )
          |
       [ Bob ]
```

Then read this [FAQ examples about configuring OpenBSD PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/queueing.html#example1) for this. Theses examples shows you how to apply **egress and ingress shaping** to individual "clients" (IP addresses and ports in fact).

Connect your multiple WAN links to your OpenBSD (one network card per link) and then configure a [trunk(4)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-5.6/man4/trunk.4?query=trunk&sec=4&manpath=OpenBSD-5%2E6) to aggregate links as one virtual trunk interface, and then use it in `pf.conf` (in the schema above, fxp0 would be replaced by trunk0).